# Are explicit conversion operators allowed in braced initializer lists?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, compiler-bug

The following code compiles with GCC 4.9.2 but not with Clang 3.5.0:

```
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
  explicit operator std::string() const;
};

std::string bar{Foo{}}; // Works in g++, fails in clang++
std::string baz(Foo{}); // Works in both
```

clang++ says:

```
foo.cpp:9:13: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::string'
      (aka 'basic_string<char>')
std::string bar{Foo{}};
            ^  ~~~~~~~
...: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Foo' to
      'const std::basic_string<char> &' for 1st argument
      basic_string(const basic_string& __str);
      ^
```

Curiously, it works if `std::string` is replaced with a primitive type like `int`.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51553 and the linked clang non-bug are probably relevant

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a Clang bug. [over.match.list]/1:

> When objects of non-aggregate class type `T` are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - [..]
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, **overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class `T` and the argument list consists of
>     the elements of the initializer list.**

Since the second line compiles fine, there is an inconsistency: They should be equivalent when it comes to overload resolution.

Answer (score 3):

From [class.conv.fct]/2:

> A conversion function may be explicit (7.1.2), in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for direct-initialization (8.5).

So the question is how you initialize your objects. Clearly `baz` is direct-initialized, so this works. By contrast, `bar` is direct-list-initialized, but not direct-initialized, and so the explicit conversion is not available.

Comment: I think it fails in Clang also with a non-explicit conversion function

Comment: @PiotrS. Wow you're right, that's crazy.  That's definitely a Clang bug right?

Comment: @TavianBarnes I don't know, I'm curious too

Answer (score 2):

clang doesn't seem to care whether the conversion operator is `explicit` or not, and I believe it is correct due to the wording in *[over.best.ics]*.

First of all, the *direct-initialization*

```
std::string baz(Foo{});
```

works on both gcc and clang, and is explained by *[class.conv.fct]/2* as mentioned in [KerrekSB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27574235/241631).

The *direct-list-initialization*

```
std::string bar{Foo{}};
```

on the other hand, does not consider *any* user defined conversions, `explicit` or not.

Quoting N3337, *§13.3.3.1/4* **[over.best.ics]**

> However, **when considering the argument of a constructor** or user-defined conversion function that is a candidate by 13.3.1.3 when invoked for the copying/moving of the temporary in the second step of a class copy-initialization, by 13.3.1.7 when passing the initializer list as a single argument or **when the initializer list has exactly one element and a conversion to some class X** or reference to (possibly cv-qualified) X **is considered for the first parameter of a constructor of X**, or by 13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5, or 13.3.1.6 in all cases, **only standard conversion sequences and ellipsis conversion sequences are considered**.

Comment: Is it possible that section talks about initializer lists specifically (i.e. `std::initializer_list`), and not braced init-lists in general?

Comment: And I suppose if you're right then clang is wrong for accepting the code when `std::string` is replaced with `int`?

Comment: @Tavian No, I'm pretty sure it means braced-init-lists because the 13.3.1.7 mentioned in there covers list-initialization in general. And I don't know the answer to your second question. The quoted paragraph mentioned `class X` all over, so maybe that means it only applies to user defined types? You should add the `int` observation to your clang bug report so you get an answer to both.