# C++ Ifstream object equals nullptr but it isn't a pointer?

Tags: c++

I was trying a test program on failures of opening a file using `ifstream`. The code is below :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs ("wrong_filename.txt");
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << is_pointer<decltype(ifs)>::value <<"\n";
    cout << (ifs==nullptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is :-

```
false
true
```

If `ifs` is not a `pointer`, then how does it equal to `nullptr`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Until C++11, C++ streams are implicitly convertible to `void*`. The result will be `NULL` if the stream is not in an errorless state and something else if it is. So `ifs == NULL` (should not work with `nullptr`, see below) will find and use that conversion, and since your filename was wrong, the comparison will yield true.

In C++11, this was changed to an explicit conversion to `bool`, with `false` indicating an error and `true` a good stream, because the `void*` conversion allowed too much nonsensical code, such as your example. Indeed, a current compiler in C++11 or C++14 mode will reject your snippet, [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff411520d28973ed). Since your code is obviously at least C++11, your compiler is non-conforming by accepting it.

Those conversions allow and are intended for error checks like this:

```
if ( !(ifs >> data) )
    std::cout << "Reading data failed.";
```

or, analogous to your example:

```
std::ifstream ifs ("wrong_filename.txt");
if (!ifs)
    std::cout << "Could not open file.";
```

---

Fun fact of the day: You can also use this to cleanly loop over a file, e.g.:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(ifs, line);) {
    // Process line
}
```

Comment: @CppNITR you need a *boolean context*, that is a context which triggers explicit boolean conversions. For example, a cast to `bool`, an `if` condition, or the second part of a `for` header.

Comment: @CppNITR Because the `bool` conversion is `explicit`. Good catch, updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: casting to "bool" also fails

Comment: @CppNITR Works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73b1913dc8feecae), and should work on every conforming implementation.

Comment: _"Since your code is obviously at least C++11, your compiler is non-conforming by accepting it."_ Probably using the libstdc++ from GCC 4.x, which supported C++11 features such as `nullptr` but we didn't replace the `operator void*` with `explicit operator bool` until GCC 5.

Comment: @hvd, really?! G++ doesn't allow it, but Clang and EDG do.

Comment: @JonathanWakely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573928/are-explicit-conversion-operators-allowed-in-braced-initializer-lists Nvm, that link is for class types, there might be a difference.

Comment: @hvd, I think clang is correct to reject it for class types, but correct to accept it for `bool`, and GCC is wrong. See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51553 and http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=17376 where Richard quotes [over.best.ics]p4

Comment: @JonathanWakely Seems like I've been getting the wrong picture in my head, with a somewhat warped interpretation of the standard to support GCC's behaviour. A quick re-read so far does indeed not appear to support the rules as I had remembered them. Will need to re-read in more detail later, thanks for letting me know.