# Invalid Operands to binary expression after switching from g++ to clang++ Error occurs in assert

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, assert, clang++

I appreciate any help on this matter, I've googled and searched around a bit and I'm missing what's going on or how to fix it.

I have a code previously compiled on the command line with g++ that I have made a make file for and I'm testing out using the clang complier.  I have not had an issue with it prior to now..

Here's the error

```
input.cpp:241:17: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>')
  and 'long')
            assert(casFile!=NULL);
                   ~~~~~~~^ ~~~~
```

The code section it is coming from is

```
char outfile[32],casfile[32];
ifstream outFile, casFile;

....other stuff unrelated...

casFile.open(casfile);
assert(casFile!=NULL);
```

At the top of the file

```
#include "input.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
```

I'm a little confused because I have been using this just fine until I switched to clang.  Is there a flag I am missing?

```
-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wall
```

I think I included all the relevant info.  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187086/c-ifstream-object-equals-nullptr-but-it-isnt-a-pointer. Prior to C++11, streams were implicitly convertible to `void*`, but not in C++11. Instead a conversion to `bool` was allowed so `assert(casFile);` does what you want since a good stream is converted to `true`.

Comment: Jonathan Wakely in the above link discusses issues with GCC as well.